# Can we set a new key equal to an array element in $project statement?

Tags: mongodb

In mongo, I can do this:

```
db.HI.aggregate({$project: {new_val: '$tags.first'}})
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
db.HI.aggregate({$project: {new_val: '$my_array.0'}})
```

Does it mean that aggregation doesn't support array in this way? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently the aggregation framework doesn't yet support this, there's an in progress JIRA ticket for this **[here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589)** and [**there**](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074).

An alternative is to first [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the array, then [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) the deconstructed array documents by the `_id` key. In the grouped documents, retrieve the first array element with the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) [group accumulator operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/):

```
db.HI.aggregate([
    { 
        "$unwind": "$my_array" 
    },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "new_val": { "$first": "$my_array" }
        }
    }
])
```